# Most efficient javascript test for valid colour values (hex and RGB) and capture the colour value

Tags: javascript, regex, colors

The challenge is to take a string value (in JavaScript) and:

a) Determine if the string value is a valid colour representation (3-digit hex, 6-digit hex or rgb value)

b) Retrieve the valid colour value (e.g. the 3 hex digits, the 3 hex pairs, or the 3 rgb values)

c) Do this as efficiently as possible.

I have the following regex expressions, which work, but I need to make them as efficient as possible.

For the RGB(r,g,b) match, to ensure r,g & b values are 0-255, and allow an r,g,b match only (e.g. input is "255,255,255" or "255, 255, 255" or "rgb(255,255,255)", etc.)

```
re = /^rgb\(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),\s*([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),\s*([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\)$|^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),\s*([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),\s*([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/;
```

For a 6-digit hex value (e.g. "FFFFFF"):

```
re = /^([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$/;
```

And for a 3-digit hex value (e.g. "FFF"):

```
re = /^([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])$/;
```

For each of these I then use:

```
result = re.exec(value);
if (result) {
    // process using e.g. result[1], result[2] & result[3] as needed
}
```

Are these the most efficient regex expressions to achieve this? Or is there a better way, perhaps not using regex?

(Credits: This is resolving invalid matches discovered in the RGB Colour Parser code by Stoyan at http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript)

Comment: Hm... you may make the test even more efficient if you code the test in plain javascript rather than using the regular expressions.

Comment: yeah, regexp might not be the best solution here.  also be aware that hex codes may be preceeded by `#`

Comment: Yes indeed, the full code accounts for the possibility of a single leading '#'. I'm also not discounting the idea of replacing the regex with plain javascript and would be interested in a suggested answer (I've updated the question to reflect that it's an acceptable answer)

Comment: I think it doesn't match `rgb(255 , 255 , 255)` with one or more whitespaces before the comma.

Comment: Here's a library that does it without regex - https://github.com/deanm/css-color-parser-js/blob/master/csscolorparser.js

Comment: @insertusernamehere In the page, it says 'Any leading # is stripped; spaces are stripped' which the OP probably isn't doing.

Comment: @insertusernamehere That's correct, it doesn't (though it should and can be easily updated if the principle is correct).

Comment: @JeffEscalante that library looks very interesting. I'll do some testing.

Comment: What are your criteria for "efficient"? Is that least processing power? Fastest execution (on a range of browsers)? Least code? Easiest to write? Easiest to maintain? Or some weighted combination of the above?

Comment: @RobG most efficient in this case means fastest execution on a range of browsers with least processing power. (As it will be called on each keyup in an input field)

Comment: @Chris–I'd be amazed if any of the solutions here took more than 0.1ms to run for a simple string, mine (which is not optimised for speed at all) gets [over 200k ops/sec](http://jsperf.com/colourstring) on a modest laptop. Better to go for functional, clear and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO regular expressions should be used if any other solution fails. So this is my approach:

```
var color = "(...)";
var fetchedValue;

/**
 * @param searchString
 * @return string
 */
function getHexValue(searchString) {
    var noHash = searchString.replace("#","");
    if ((noHash.length !== 6 && noHash.length !== 3) || noHash.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]/g).length < noHash.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return noHash;
}

/**
 * @param searchString
 * @return array
 */
function getRGBValue(searchString) {
    var ingredients = searchString.match(/\d{,3}/g);
    for (var i in ingredients) {
        if (parseInt(ingredients[i]) > 255) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return ingredients;
}

if ('#' == color.substring(0, 1)) { // the color is in HEX
    fetchedValue = getHexValue(color);
} else {
    fetchedValue = getRGBValue(color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks matewka, but your regex expressions don't validate the input values. I could easily enter `#MAP` and get `MAP` as the result, or `999,999,999` which is not a valid RGB value.

Comment: To save you time, the current regex is already including in the question, which is about whether it's the most efficient method or not.

Comment: The getHexValue() function is an interesting way of doing it indeed. Not tested, but looks good. Code needs to also resolve the RGB values validating to 3 values in the range 0-255. But it looks like a good start.

Comment: Another update, this time on `getRGBValue` function. I used a loop which I regard not the best solution in this particular case but I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38979/discussion-between-chris-and-matewka)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want, lightly tested. No doubt it can be reduced further, but I'm not sure it's worth it. It's about 15 lines of code with the comments removed.

It depends on support for *forEach* so either shim it or replace with for loops. The strategy is to tokenise the input, then deal with the bits (just like a parser):

```
/* Accept:
**   number triplets: xxx,xxx,xxx
**   rgb values     : rgb(xxx,xxx,xxx)
**   Hex values     : xxxxxx and xxxx
**   prefixed hex   : #xxxxxx and #xxx
*/
function parseColourString(s) {

  // Tokenise input
  var m = s.match(/^\#|^rgb\(|[\d\w]+$|\d{3}/g);

  // Other variables
  var value, values;
  var valid = true, double = false;

  // If no matches, return false
  if (!m) return false;

  // If hex value
  if (m.length < 3) {
    // Get the value
    value = m[m.length-1];

    // Split into parts, either x,x,x or xx,xx,xx
    values = value.length == 3? double = true && value.split('') : value.match(/../g);

    // Convert to decimal values - if #nnn, double up on values 345 => 334455
    values.forEach(function(v,i){values[i] = parseInt(double? ''+v+v : v, 16);});

  // Otherwise it's rgb, get the values
  } else {
    values = m.length == 3? m.slice() : m.slice(1);
  }

  // Check that each value is between 0 and 255 inclusive and return the result
  values.forEach(function(v){valid = valid? v >= 0 && v <= 255 : false;});

  // If string is invalid, return false, otherwise return an array of the values
  return valid && values;
}

console.log(parseColourString('#345fff'));            // [52, 95, 255]
console.log(parseColourString('#a3b'));               // [170, 51, 187]
console.log(parseColourString('#aa33bb'));            // [170, 51, 187]
console.log(parseColourString('a3b3c3'));             // [163, 179, 195]
console.log(parseColourString('rgb(123, 123, 123)')); // ["123", "123", "123"]
console.log(parseColourString('123, 123, 123'));      // ["123", "123", "123"]
console.log(parseColourString('aeiou'));              // false
console.log(parseColourString(''));                   // false
console.log(parseColourString('rgb(123,234,345)'));   // false
```